# How to launch app from another app in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, uri, windows-8.1, windows-10, launch

I want to launch my app from another app in the Windows Phone 8.1 environment. I followed the instructions in MSDN, but I cannot figure out how to call the first app from the second. This is the protocol I added in the first app's manifest file:

```
<Extensions>
    <Extension Category="windows.protocol">
      <Protocol Name="myapp">
        <Logo>Assets\SmallLogo.scale-240.png</Logo>
        <DisplayName>my App 1</DisplayName>
      </Protocol>
    </Extension>
  </Extensions>
```

This is my call from the second app, that does absolutely nothing:

```
private async void btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new System.Uri("myapp:"));
    }
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce your issue, I can launch the target app. Have you already deploy your target app myapp?

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps in [Auto-launching apps using file and URI associations for Windows Phone 8](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj206987(v=vs.105).aspx#BKMK_URIassociations)

And you have use use a class which is derived from `UriMapperBase` to handle the navigation and have to set it as `RootFrame.UriMapper` in the App.xaml.cs

```
private void InitializePhoneApplication()
{
    if (phoneApplicationInitialized)
        return;

    // Create the frame but don't set it as RootVisual yet; this allows the splash
    // screen to remain active until the application is ready to render.
    RootFrame = new PhoneApplicationFrame();
    RootFrame.Navigated += CompleteInitializePhoneApplication;

    // Assign the URI-mapper class to the application frame.
    RootFrame.UriMapper = new AssociationUriMapper();

    ******
}
```